# Criteria for deleting variables in factor analysis

Tags: factor-analysis

Does it have importance in conventional PCA/factor analysis which of the criteria: communality and loading problems is taken into consideration for deleting variables in the conventional PCA/factor analysis? (should I first delete the variables that have a low communality or the variables that have cross-loadings?)

Comment: I would suggest to formulate a general question regarding selection of items or aggregation of items into unidimensional scales.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! This question in not about aggregating items in scales, its about the criteria that are used for deleting items in factor analysis.